# why is my AdMob interstitial shown only once ?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, interstitial

I'm using admob interstitial on my app. I'm able to display the interstitial only one time, but I have no idea how to request a new intertstitial. lease help me !

my code is as follow ?

```
  using UnityEngine;
```

using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdsMnager : MonoBehaviour {

```
public static AdsMnager Instance { 
    get ; 
    set;
}
public bool InterstitialLoaded = false;
public bool InterstitialClosed = false ;
const string InterstitialAdId ="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
const string BannerAdId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
AdRequest request;
private BannerView bannerView;


private void Awake()
{
    if (Instance == null)
        Instance = this;
    else
        Destroy (gameObject);
    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd (InterstitialAdId);

    Showbanner ();
    request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ();
    interstitialAd.LoadAd (request);
}
public void RequestBanner()
{
    bannerView = new BannerView (BannerAdId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ();
    bannerView.LoadAd (request);
    bannerView.Show ();

}
public void Showbanner()
{
    if (bannerView == null)
        RequestBanner ();
}

public void ShowInterstitial()
{
    request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ();
    interstitialAd.LoadAd (request);
    if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded ()) {

        InterstitialLoaded = true;
        interstitialAd.Show ();
    } else {

    }

    interstitialAd.OnAdClosed += InterstitialAd_onAdClosed;
}

private void InterstitialAd_onAdClosed (object sender , System.EventArgs e)
{
    InterstitialLoaded = false;
    InterstitialClosed = true;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can request for a new ad in the `#onAdClosed()` callback method. Just modify your `#InterstitialAd_onAdClosed()` method like so:

```
private void InterstitialAd_onAdClosed (object sender , System.EventArgs e)
{
    InterstitialLoaded = false;
    InterstitialClosed = true;
    interstitialAd.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build())

}
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't wotk. Thanks for replying though